# Export Jqgrid data to excel using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using Jqgrid 3.7 every thing works fine and now i want to export the data to excel on click event. I am using Load Once method which makes loading and filtering of huge data in a faster way. Can any one suggest any help to fix this issue. I am using asp.net 4.0 and not MVC.